# Justify content between - inside nav bar in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, navbar

I've seen a similar question here but that answer didn't worked for me.

So the problem is that I want to justify content inside nav bar in bootstrap.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto justify-content-between">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle navbarDropdown" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Our Team</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle navbarDropdown" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Status</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle navbarDropdown" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Our Sevices</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contribute</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Here's a live example : https://jsfiddle.net/oberknezev/adcybshm/1/

"Home" item should go to all the way to the left and "contributors" all the way to the right with space between items justifed.

Tried with inline d-flex class, justify-content-between but nothing changes.

I guess it's something stupid but after 3 hours of trying, squinting, searching and reading all the stuff, I'm still lost why this isn't working when it's working on some simpler examples that I've tried.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to specify that the nav flexbox needs to take up all of the available space of the parent element. You can do that by adding flex: 1 to it, like below:

```
.navbar-nav,
.mr-auto {
flex: 1;
margin: auto !important;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know a way to make what you need, but... I don't know if it is a correct way to solve that.
In your `<ul>` tag, add the Bootstrap class `.w-100`. Example below:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-between">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

That class is the same to say you're given a 100% width to your `<ul>` So...
If you're using a old Bootstrap version, you can give a class to your `<ul>` like `.Width` and give that class a width of your choice, like below:

```
.Width
{
    width: 100%;
}
```